# Connectors - Conjunctive adverbs

Tags: grammar-identification

I am learning German B2/C1 and have covered *Hauptsätze* and *Nebensätze* and the connectors such as *denn* and *weil*. I am also familiar with *Relativsätze*.

Something I realised from speaking German is that there is another kind of sub-sentence introduced by using adverbs, for instance:

> Sie will den Sonnenuntergang sehen, deshalb ist sie jetzt am Strand.

This doesn't seem to fall into the category *Haupstsatz* (verb in second place after the connector) or *Nebensatz* (verb at the end) as the verb appears directly after the connector. Does this kind of sub-sentence have a name and what are its grammatical rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grammatically, *deshalb* is an adverb, at least in this sentence. *Deshalb ist sie jetzt am Strand,* is a grammatical sentence on it's own and what you're seeing is two grammatical sentences in tandem. This is allowed in English if they are separated by a semicolon, but German also allows a comma for the same purpose. The technical name in English is [Conjunctive adverb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_adverb) and some examples are "therefore" and "similarly". The technical name in German is [Konjunktionaladverb](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktionaladverb), and some other examples are *trotzdem* and *jedoch*.

Since these are technically adverbs, they don't have to be placed at the beginning of a clause. The German Wikipedia article gives the example *Draußen schneit es. Ich gehe trotzdem zu Fuß.*

In English, you're "supposed" to separate a conjunctive adverb from a preceding clause with a semicolon. But I don't think a lot of people really follow this rule or notice when it's not followed. For example the English Wikipedia article on [Cogito, ergo sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito,_ergo_sum) translates it as "I think, therefore I am." Using a comma in German is allowed so it's perfectly correct to say *Ich denke, also bin ich.*